# How to bring the ZTE K3806-Z 3G under RedHat Enterprise Linux 6 to life?

Tags: rhel, 3g

since my other thread was closed: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/56448/zte-k3806-z-3g-rhel-6

I opened a new one:

Did anyone managed to bring the ZTE K3806-Z modem to life (with vodafone) on RHEL 6? How to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1)

## this first part is needed because linux needs to see this device as a modem, not as an usb storage:

```
vi /lib/udev/rules.d/40-usb_modeswitch.rules
...
grep 1013 /lib/udev/rules.d/40-usb_modeswitch.rules 
ATTRS{idVendor}=="19d2",ATTRS{idProduct}=="1013",RUN+="/usr/sbin/eject %k" 
ATTRS{idVendor}=="19d2",ATTRS{idProduct}=="1013",RUN+="usb_modeswitch '%b/%k'"
```

2)

## install wvdial (usb_modeswitch is needed to recognize the device as a 3g modem)

```
yum install wvdial usb_modeswitch
```

3)

## plug in the ZTE K3806 USB 3G modem, see dmesg messages, just type "dmesg" in the command line:

4)

## configure wvdial

## if PIN is: 1234 - modifiy the PIN:

```
echo '[Dialer Defaults] 
Init1 = ATZ+CPIN=1234 
Init2 = ATQ0 V1 E1 S0=0 &C1 &D2 +FCLASS=0 
Init3 = AT+CGDCONT=1,"IP","standardnet.vodafone.net" 
Modem Type = Analog Modem 
Baud = 115200 
New PPPD = yes 
Modem = /dev/ttyACM0 
ISDN = 0 
Dial Command = ATDT 
Phone = *99***1# 
Password = vodafone 
Username = vodafone 
Stupid Mode = 1 
Auto DNS=Off' > /etc/wvdial.conf
```

## 5)

## NOT NEEDED

## chmod 666 /etc/ppp/peers/wvdial

## 6)

## NOT NEEDED

## plug in the ZTE K3806 modem & network manager will pop-up for PIN, type the PIN then modem LED turns blue..

## If it didn't asks for PIN.. then try to modeswitch it to a modem with the sakis3g!

7)

## as user in a console:

```
wvdial
```

## if wvdial says "/dev/ttyACM0 is busy" then disable network in nm-applet (networmanager) - because probably that's the app that keeps it busy:

```
pkill nm-applet
```

8) 
update /etc/resolv.conf if there isn't any DNS! (hint with example IP's):

```
cat /etc/resolv.conf 
nameserver 1.2.3.4
nameserver 1.2.3.4
```